# How can I increase the thickness of the sashes in centered layout in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Reproducibility:

Change into centered layout: View > Appearance > Centered Layout

See the handles on the side. You can resize the viewpoint with them.
I find it hard, to grab the line, because it's so small.

[image]

How can I increase the thickness of them, so I can grab them easier?

They can be finicky by default, since the area to grab them, is insanely small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not by using the `workbench.sash.size` setting, then it might be a bug. But that setting applies just fine to centered layout for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helps to make their color more obvious, with this `colorCustomization` in your `settings.json`:

```json
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "editorGroup.border": "#676565",
    "sash.hoverBorder": "#ff0000",
  }
```

Comment: I am not concerned about the visibility. It's tricky to get the cursor to switch into the mode, that allows me to move it.